# Wrapper for siunitx' \SI macro to automatically split number and unit

Tags: macros, siunitx, expl3, units

### Problem

I use the `siunitx`-package to typeset numbers and units with correct spacing etc. There is a command

```
\SI{<number>}{<unit>}
```

for that. However, it would be much easier to write something like

```
\xSI{<number and unit>}
```

and let LaTeX automatically split the number and the unit and call `\SI{}{}` internally.

```
\xSI{9.81m/s^2}  →  \SI{9.81}{m/s^2}
\xSI{1e-3m}      →  \SI{1e-3}{m}
```

I know that `expl3` provides some regex-functionality, but as I am only familiar with "regular" LaTeX I do not know where to start.

### Question

How can I write a wrapper function for `SI{}{}` (using `expl3`?) so that the number and the unit parts get automatically split?

Comment: So all the trouble to save `}{` keystrokes ?

Comment: I was thinking the same as percusse.  Is this really your final intention?

Comment: @percusse Why not use a proper editor with Auto-Completion? `\SI` followed by `Ctrl` + `<Space>` gives me `\SI{<cursor>}{}` where I can easily “over-tab” the `}{`.

Comment: No, I'm not *that* lazy – I had to convert a pdf back to LaTeX, with lots of units in it. I wrote a script that fixes umlauts, unicode characters and line breaks, so I could copy-paste most of the document. However, it was a pain to fix the units, because pasting gave me something like `9, 81 m/s2` (not the spaces). I thought of a command in which I could wrap everything unit-related and LaTeX would do the rest. Also, this could be a good way to show what is possible in LaTeX3 and a good starting point for me to get more familiar with the `expl3`-syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You find a regular expression for numbers in scientific format [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xSI}{ O{} m }
 {
  \ralfix_split:n { #2 }
  \ralfix_si:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__ralfix_pieces_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ralfix_split:n #1
 {
  \regex_split:nnN
   {
    ( [ - + ]? [0-9]* [\.\,]? [0-9]+ ( [eE] [-+]? [0-9]+ )? )
    (.*)
   }
   { #1 }
   \l__ralfix_pieces_seq
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ralfix_si:n #1
 {
  \use:x
   {
    \exp_not:n {\SI[#1]}
    {\seq_item:Nn \l__ralfix_pieces_seq {2}}
    {\seq_item:Nn \l__ralfix_pieces_seq {4}}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\xSI{9.81m/s^2}

\xSI{1e-3m}

\xSI[output-decimal-marker={,}]{1,2e-33kV}
\end{document}
```

The function could be refined by first examining item number 1 in the resulting sequence, that will be non empty if no match has been found.

***This said, I would recommend you using*** `\SI{...}{...}` ***which is not much more difficult to type and clearly separates different things from each other.***

[image]

Comment: I had to add unit-formatting afterwards, so autocomplete was not a big help. Your solution is just perfect, thank you very much!